# Do flamenco guitarists use distinctive chords?

Tags: harmony, chord-theory, flamenco, flamenco-guitar

Classical guitarist here. Does flamenco guitar use distinctive chords (other than, say, the major, minor, augmented, and diminished triads and seventh chords), or is it just the favored modes, chord progressions, rhythm, dynamics, timbre, dances, and playing techniques that distinguish it from other styles?

Aside from "the chords themselves," are there certain voicings they tend to favor?

Comment: Have you at least looked up some basic music reference sources? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flamenco#Music

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I'm not sure that source answers my question. For example, it mentions the Andalusian cadence and the flamenco mode, but my question is about the chords themselves, not about modes and not about cadences. Unless perhaps you are hinting, by the source's apparent silence with respect to my question, that the answer to my question is no.

Comment: There are a whole lot of musics that all use "the same chords," at least from an instrument-agnostic sense, and that differentiate by what they do with them. There may well be some flamenco-specific guitaristic technical considerations.

Comment: @NoahJ, in the wiki article "cadence" isn't used in the technical sense, it's a chord progression. But the wiki article is just an example of one source. I'm really asking if you have looked up anything? Like Andy Bonner commented a lot of the chord/scale material will be like other music.

Comment: Instant fake flamenco chord: 023100.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a Flamenco player, but one thing that seems noticeable to me is a characteristic use of open strings. A few examples...

[image]

...and...

[image]

Those came out of a method book: Essential Flamenco Guitar: Volume 1: An In-Depth Course for Absolute Beginners to More Advanced Players.

Notice the open `E` string above both an `A` and `Bb` bass? That particular method book doesn't get into harmony theory, but in my mind I think of this kind of an `E` over a bass/root `Bb` as less a chord tone and more a *pedal* or *drone*. At least part of the purpose, beyond sustaining tones of the tonic chord, is to make the guitar more resonant.

Also, I notice those chord changes over the `E` drone use a lot of half step changes.

Here is another passage that just begins to touch on harmony theory...

[image]

The book says the root (tonic) chord will be the `A` major chord, but the tonality is *phrygian* with a sort of vague reference to `D` minor.

Notice the chord list (`A Bb C7 C Dm`) is all diatonic to `D` minor, yet the tonic is `A`. (Notice also the open `E` string drone for all the chords listed.) That list may seem strange if one expected all the chord to be diatonic to an `A` phrygrian scale. Without going into a long description of phrygian modal harmony, one quick and dirty way to describe, in my own words, is: *play in a minor key but treat the dominant major triad `V` chord as the tonic*.

Those are at least two chord/harmony strategies to take, use open string drones and try the quick and dirty guideline to play in phrygian mode. I would look into some other study sources to flesh that out. Look for transcriptions of authentic Flamenco guitar. Beyond that, the real heart of Flamenco as I understand will be much more about rhythm and strumming/plucking technique.